# Why is my results array returning as empty in this mongo query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my query I'm new to Mongo so I'm kind of fumbling through this query. My goal is to get the teammates of the player supplied. I will show the query and then the document for the player.

```
db.Players.aggregate([{
    $match: {_id: "/players/c/cruzne02.shtml"}}, 
    {$unwind: "$teams"},
    {$unwind: "$teams.years"}, 
    {$lookup: {
        from: "Players",
        let: {team_name: "$teams.name", team_year: "$teams.years"},
        pipeline: [{
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $and: [
                        {$eq: ["$teams.name", "$$team_name"]},
                        {$eq: ["$teams.years", "$$team_year"]},
                    ]
                }
            },
        }],
        as: "results"
    }},
    {$unwind: {
        path: "$results",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }}, 
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            team: "$teams.name",
            year: "$teams.years"
        },
        results: {
            $push: "$results"
        }
    }}, 
    {$project: {
        team: "$_id.team",
        year: "$_id.year",
        results: 1,
        _id: 0
    }}
]);
```

```
{
    "_id": "/players/c/cruzne02.shtml",
    "url": "/players/c/cruzne02.shtml",
    "name": "Nelson Cruz",
    "image": "https://www.baseball-reference.com/req/202108020/images/headshots/f/fea2f131_mlbam.jpg",
    "teams": [{
        "name": "MIL",
        "years": [2005]
    }, {
        "name": "TEX",
        "years": [2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
    }, {
        "name": "BAL",
        "years": [2014]
    }, {
        "name": "SEA",
        "years": [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
    }, {
        "name": "MIN",
        "years": [2019, 2020, 2021]
    }, {
        "name": "TBR",
        "years": [2021]
    }]
}
```

I'm able to get the group back but the results array is always empty. The teams and years line up but the results never populates.
My current result has empty arrays what do I need to change.

EDIT: Here's my result

```
[ { results: [], team: 'MIN', year: 2020 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2006 },
  { results: [], team: 'MIL', year: 2005 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2008 },
  { results: [], team: 'TBR', year: 2021 },
  { results: [], team: 'SEA', year: 2018 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2007 },
  { results: [], team: 'MIN', year: 2019 },
  { results: [], team: 'SEA', year: 2017 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2013 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2011 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2012 },
  { results: [], team: 'SEA', year: 2016 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2010 },
  { results: [], team: 'SEA', year: 2015 },
  { results: [], team: 'BAL', year: 2014 },
  { results: [], team: 'MIN', year: 2021 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2009 } ]
```

Comment: please supply some sample data

Comment: Show show us some input data. I doubt you need all these `$unwind` and `$group`

Comment: I'm trying to get all the teammates of the player with the id in the match part of the aggregate. I want to a return an array of objects that contain an array of documents, for the specific team name and year. So I want all the players that have team.name equal to MIL and team.years equal to 2005. Do that for each year inside the given player.

Comment: In the $lookup stage, `"$teams.name"` will be an array, which will never be `$eq` a string, and `$teams.years` will be an array of arrays of integers, which will never be `$eq` an integer.  If I get some time later, I'll see if I can think of a solution to this.

Comment: This is my result
`[ { results: [], team: 'MIN', year: 2020 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2006 },
  { results: [], team: 'MIL', year: 2005 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2008 },
  { results: [], team: 'TBR', year: 2021 },
  { results: [], team: 'SEA', year: 2018 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2007 },
  { results: [], team: 'MIN', year: 2019 },
  { results: [], team: 'SEA', year: 2017 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2013 },
  { results: [], team: 'TEX', year: 2011 }, ]` etc.

Comment: You should edit the question to add that result.  The result is exactly what I would expect to see if the $lookup matched 0 documents.

Comment: So how can I change my lookup so it returns what I'm looking for? How come it won't just match whats in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `$match` in the end of aggregate.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$teams"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$teams.years"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        team: "$teams.name",
        year: "$teams.years",
        
      },
      results: {
        $push: {
          "name": "$name",
          "id": "$_id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "results.id": "/players/c/cruzne02.shtml"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/590CGe3o6Mk)

Comment: This is close but I added another player that overlaps with this player and should show up for `"MIN":2020` and `"MIN":2021`  [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5Jx4x3eIO3_)

Comment: i update my answer

Comment: I supplied the `$match` because I want to get every teammate of that specific player with that id not just every team in the whole database which is what the query above does.

Comment: i update my answer again, put match in the end of aggregate